# Largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers with C

Tags: c, algorithm

The code is trying to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers. The answer is 91*99 = 9009 but I keep getting 990, which is not even a palindrome. I really appreciate the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 10;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int array[100] = {0};
    int divider = 10;
    int num;
    int great;
    int product;
    int n;
    int flag;

    /*Loop through first 2 digit number and second 2 digit number*/

    while (i<100)
    {
        while (j < 100)
        {
            product = i*j;
            array [a] = product % 10;
            n = product / divider; 

            while (n != 0)
            {
                a++; 
                num = n%10;
                divider *=10;
                array[a]=num;
                n = product/divider;
            }

            flag = 0;

            while (b<a) 
            {
                if (array[b] != array[a])
                {
                    flag = 1;   
                }
                b++;
                a--;
            }

            if (flag == 0)
            {
                great = product;
            }

            j++;
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
        }     
        i++;
    }

    printf("The largest palindrome is %d \n", great);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you get something that is not a palindrome, have you tried to focus on the part of the code that checks if a number is palindrome or not? Try to narrow your problem...

Comment: Just a comment on the code... Rather than using one monolithic code block, split it into functions... like `int is_palindrome(int in)`. It will be easier to understand and debug

Comment: Just a comment on algorithm... you are trying to find the largest palindrome number... So it is better to start checking the product the from the highest point and stopping when you find the first palindrome number.

Comment: Now that palindromes that are products of two two-digit decimals are discussed at length, what about `3-digit numbers` as per title?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet you can try.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
int a = 1;      // first integer
int b = 1;     // second integer
int currentNumber;      
int currentPalin;      if a palindrome is found, its stored here

while (a<100){      //loop through the first number

        while (b<100){      // loop through the second number
            currentNumber = a*b;
            if (currentNumber == reverse(currentNumber) ){      //check for palindrome
                currentPalin = currentNumber;

            }
            b = b+1;      //increment the second number

        }
        b = a; // you could have set b=1 but it would not be an efficient algorithm because
            //some of the multiplication would occur twice. eg- (54*60) and (60*54)
        a = a +1;      //increment the first number
    }
printf ("Largest palindrom is %d  \n", currentPalin);

getchar();

}
// method for finding out reverse
int reverse(int n){
    int reverse = 0;



 while (n != 0)
{
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + n%10; 

// when you divide a number by 10, the 
//remainder gives you the last digit. so you are reconstructing the 
//digit from the last

    n = n/10;
}

return reverse;


}
```

**Update:-**  As suggested by M Oehm, I have modified the code to make it more general.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int currentNumber;
int currentPalin=0;

while (a<100){

        while (b<100){
            currentNumber = a*b;
            if (currentNumber == reverse(currentNumber) ){
                if (currentNumber>currentPalin){
                        currentPalin = currentNumber;                       
                    }

            }
            b = b+1;

        }
        b = 1; 
        a = a +1;
    }
if (currentPalin==0){
    printf("No Palindrome exits in this range");
}
else {
    printf ("Largest palindrome is %d  \n", currentPalin);
}

getchar();

}

int reverse(int n){
    int reverse = 0;



 while (n != 0)
{
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + n%10;
    n = n/10;
}

return reverse;


}
```

Comment: Your algorithm misses out on squares. (As it happens, there are no palindrome squares in the given range, but they still should be checked.) You also assume that the last palindrome is the highest one, which is true here, because one of the factors is 99, but if we ignote the products of 99, there's `97 * 55 == 5335`, which is smaller than `96 * 88 == 8448`, although is is calculated later in the loops. You really have to check whether the product is greater than the currently best match.

Comment: Also, please initialise `currentPalin` to a suitable defualt, so that you can tell whether there are any palindromes found at all.

Comment: Thank you! @MOehm , I have updated the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to solve the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int reverse(int num)
{
    int result = 0;
    while( num > 0)
    {
        result = result * 10 + (num%10);
        num/=10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int last_best = 1;
    int best_i=1;
    int best_j = 1;
    const int max_value = 99;

    for( int i = max_value ; i > 0 ; --i)
    {
        for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; --j){
            int a = i * j;
            if( last_best > a )
                break;
            else if ( a == reverse(a) )
            {
                last_best = a;
                best_i = i;
                best_j = j;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d and %d = %d\n", best_i,best_j,last_best);
}
```

And it is quite simple to follow.

Comment: Your solution makes the same error as phositronax's: You assume that the highest palindrome occurs first in your nested loop, but that isn't necessarily so in the general case. (It is here, because one of the factors is 99.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not reinitialize variables at the beginning of loop. They keeps values from previous iterations. For example, `j` and `divider`. Put

```
  j = 10;
```

before starting "j" loop, i.e.:

```
   j = 10;
   while (j < 100) ...
```

The same for divider:

```
     ...
     j = 10;
     while (j < 100) {
             divider = 10;
             ...
```

If you were using `for` loops you would avoid this problem naturally:

```
for(i=10; i<100; i++) {
  for(j=10; j<100; j++) { 
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: why **j** has to be initialized to 0 everytime? ..it is one of the numbers of the two product.

Comment: He probably wants to check all combinations of `i` and `j`, not only `0` against all `j` and the remaining `i` against `100`.

Comment: both i and j are incrementing at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @wrangler at the moment when `i` is incremented from 10 to 11, `j` equals 100 and it is never reinitialized to 10, so the next iteration for `i==11` even does not enter the body of the inner loop.